# Index:145 Uncaught TypeError: map.mapTypes.insertAt is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm never used Google Maps API before, and I can't find any similar issues to this posted online. I'm doing something really basic here,
I just want to layer OpenSeaMaps on top of Google Maps.

And I've seen a couple of code samples online so I use the below code and I get an issue where `map.mapTypes.insertAt is not a function` but I've looked at the documentation and this doesn't seem to have been deprecated and is in a couple of examples for Google Maps API, for example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay

Does anyone know why this would be throwing this error?

```
  var map;

  function initMap() {

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: { lat: 35.1264, lng: 33.4299 },
            mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'OSM']
   });


    var osmMapTypeOptions = {
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                return "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/" +
                    zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            isPng: true,
            maxZoom: 19,
            minZoom: 0,
            name: "OSM"
     };


    var osmMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(osmMapTypeOptions);


    map.setMapTypeId('OSM');
    map.mapTypes.insertAt(0, osmMapType); 

  }
```

Comment: So you don't actually use `map.mapTypes.insertAt` anywhere in your code, but still get that error message?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? You mean if I comment it out?

Comment: In the code snippet you provided, there is no occurence of `map.mapTypes.insertAt`. Did you leave out that part where it occurs, or is that all you have?

Comment: The last line is `map.mapTypes.insertAt(0, osmMapType);` - is there something more I should be doing?

Comment: Sorry, I must have been blind... I searched the page for `insertAt` but somehow didn't get any result. My bad. :)

Comment: Haha, no problem :)

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but I had the same issue a while ago (almost the same) and it was because of the google api key.

Comment: `map.mapTypes.set('OSM', osmMapType);` seems to do the trick, but all tiles are just grey. The syntax of the tiles URL seems to be wrong - can you check that?

Comment: For example, this is what one of the generated title urls would look like, but it's invalid: http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/8/153/101.png

Comment: http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/9/13/128.png - this one tile has a little asterisk on - got it from the OpenSeaMap wiki, but I can't find any more tiles with data on it based on randomly placing numbers for the x and y of the URL, I just thought I'd layer the whole thing on top of Google to test and see results. So the tile server is working but I just don't know where the data lies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MapTypesRegistry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeRegistry) doesn't have a `.insertAt` method.  See [the documentation on MapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes)

It looks to me that you want an [OverlayMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#OverlayMapTypes)

That does have an `.insertAt` method, and this works for me (note the change from `map.mapTypes.insertAt(0, osmMapType);` to `map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0,osmMapType);`:

```
var osmMapTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    return "http://t1.openseamap.org/seamark/" +
      zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  isPng: true,
  maxZoom: 19,
  minZoom: 0,
  name: "OSM"
};

var osmMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(osmMapTypeOptions);

map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0,osmMapType);
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(1,osmMapType);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ua2e5aca/)

(there doesn't seem to be much imagery at zoom levels less than 10)